# Intellij idea says Read Only File System to any file located on other drive

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, ubuntu-18.04, intellij-2020

I am using dual boot with ubuntu 18.04 installed on added SSD drive, and windows 10 installed on internal hard drive. I am facing the following problem for projects located in my hard drive, but works properly in my SSD

Whenever i am trying to save any java file i am getting the following error

[image]

Here is my file permission
[image]

And getting this error notification
[image]

I tried 'invalidate cache and restart', doesn't work.

Comment: Am I got you right that you got this issue when save on HDD from Linux? Does it help to run IDE with admin rights?

Comment: Yes. Sorry it may sound silly but how do i run as admin?

Comment: You may run it via "sudo idea".

Comment: @y.bedrov still no luck, problem remains

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?